# How to update or downgrade my iPad 3 that has a jailbreak?

Tags: itunes, ios, ipad, jailbreak

I have iPad 3 (model A1416 Wi-Fi only). It was using iOS 5.1.1 and I have then jailbroken it.

Unfortunately I allowed the device to update automatically, and didn't save the SSH blobs or any other files to enable be to revert the OS back again.

After trying some restores, I now get the black screen that tells you to plug your USB cable and connect with iTunes.

iTunes says that I have the last update and no update button is available, only restore

I have download some IPSW files for iOS 5.1.1 and iPad 7.0.4, and if I try to restore with shift in windows and browse for IPSW files and extract it, I get an error that I need to check host files etc

I have downloaded many tools like iFaith and take SSH keys from Cydia for iOS 5.1.1 and trying to make an IPSW from that give me this message:

> The provided apticket looks valid!
>
> Although the apticket is valid, the set of blobs you selected are not supported in this build of iFaith.

[image: iFaith Error per above quote]

So, I am unable to put either 5.1.1 or the latest iOS on my iPad - how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

you can not use SHSH on this device. only ipad 1 or ipad 2, nothing newer. if you need to restore you'll be forced to the latest IPSW apple is signing for that device. at the moment this is 7.0.4 if it's an ipad 3.